# how to give permissions for different users

Tags: json, node.js

### permission.json

```js
"appUser": {
        "user": {
            "read": true,
            "write": false
        },
        "packages": {
            "read": true,
            "write": false
        },
        "user_package": {
            "read": true,
            "write": false
        },
        "roles": {
            "read": true,
            "write": false
        },
        "user_detail": {
            "read": true,
            "write": false
        },
        "role_mapping": {
            "read": true,
            "write": false
        },
        "guide": {
            "read": true,
            "write": false
        },
        "guide_categories": {
            "read": true,
            "write": false
        },
        "follow_guides": {
            "read": true,
            "write": false
        },
        "pin": {
            "read": true,
            "write": false
        },
        "fav_pins": {
            "read": true,
            "write": false
        },
        "pin_guides": {
            "read": true,
            "write": false
        },
        "pin_media": {
            "read": true,
            "write": false
        },
        "category": {
            "read": true,
            "write": false
        },
        "pin_categories": {
            "read": true,
            "write": false
        },
        "company_details": {
            "read": true,
            "write": false
        },
        "person_details": {
            "read": true,
            "write": false
        },
        "interview": {
            "read": true,
            "write": false
        },
        "guide_media": {
            "read": true,
            "write": false
        },
        "thread": {
            "read": true,
            "write": false
        },
        "tutorial": {
            "read": true,
            "write": false
        },
        "comments": {
            "read": true,
            "write": false
        }
    }
```

### auth.js

```js
function verifyToken(req, res, next) {
    var func = req.query.function;
    var token = req.headers['token'];
    if (!token) {
        return res.status(401).send({
            status: 401,
            data: 'No token provided.'
        });
    }
    db.query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE token = $1', [token], function(err, data) {
        if (err) return next(err);
        db.query('SELECT role_name FROM roles r inner join role_mapping rm on r._id = rm.role_id WHERE rm.user_id = $1', [data.rows[0]._id], function(err, result) {
            if (err) return next(err);
            for(i in permission) {
                if(i == result.rows[0].role_name)
                    if(i.func.read == true)
                        console.log('you have permission');
                    console.log('you dnt have permisstion write');
            }
            if (data.rows.length == 0) {
                return res.status(404).send({
                    status: 404,
                    data: 'Failed to authenticate token.'
                });
            } else {
                next();
            }
        });
    });
}
```

I am trying to check the permission of user and I have found the role(appUser) of the user using this `for(i in permission) {
   if(i == result.rows[0].role_name)`.

I am passing `user,packages,user_packages etc` as query parameters but my question is how can I get that the user has `read` permission on this table??
I have admin, appUser and businessUser as roles. I want to give different permissions for these three users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also need to loop also to the properties of each table. (loop to read write nodes)

```
for (i in permission) { //loop tru the users
  for (j in permission[i]) { //loop tru the table permission matrix of each user
    if (j == req.query.your_query_name_of_table) { //condition for specific table
      for (k in permission[i][j]) { //loop tru properties of the table
        if (k == "read") { //because u want to check read permission only
           if (permission[i][j][k]) { //because your value is boolean
             console.log(i + " have permission to " + k + " on " + j);
           } else {
             console.log(i + " dont have permission " + k + " on " + j);
           }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Output:

> appUser have permission to read on user

OR if read is false:

Output:

> appUser dont have permission to read on user

Comment: Oops sorry, I've updated my answer. You need to go 1 more down, loop tru each user, then loop tru each table permission matrix of user, then lastly, loop tru each permission on table.

Comment: Updated again my answer for specific table and role. Comments provided for changing of the logic and more dynamic solution (eg: put it in a method, supplying the table name and specific permission).

Replace the **your_query_name_of_table ** with your query name that handles the "user"

Comment: one small clarification is it possible to select only the table that I am passing as a query parameter. Here the problem is if I give any table which is present in that json file it will be matching (i.e. I will give tutorial as query parameter and fetching, inserting or updating guide table).

Comment: The if statement here filters only the table you are passing in the query parameter. Of course it will match everything if it exists on the table, otherwise, you put a constant condition 

if (queryparam == "table_you_want")

so it will only accept the table you want to be filtered.

Comment: Pardon but I can't understand your question, base on my answer, you can parse the conditional statements there to adjust for the flow you want. Can you elaborate a little more or give an example?

Comment: [Let us continue this on the chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160593/discussion-between-m-gowda-and-tenten-ponce)

Comment: hello sir, one small doubt  `for (k in permission[i][j])` here "k" always points to read, how to make it for write??

Comment: make "if (k == "read") {" to "if (k == "read" || k == "write") {" and so on, you can add another OR statement there.